# Pagedown Escaping Special Characters in Code Sections with Django

Tags: django, escaping, markdown, html-entities, pagedown

I am using the Pagedown implementation of the Markdown editor used here on Stack Overflow, and my project is using Django. The problem I am having is that special characters like `<` in Markdown code sections are being escaped by Django, but then treated as code by Pagedown and displayed as `&lt;`.

When I type a code snippet like:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

I get the proper preview below. The `<` also properly gets saved in the db, and not the HTML entity `&lt;`.

However, when I go to output this comment on a new page, Django automatically escapes these special characters.

```
    for(var i = 0; i &lt; 10; i++)
```

I've tried turning off autoescape, but this seems to be the correct behavior, because if the user wrote

```
    <script>alert('hi');</script>
```

as a code comment, and Django did not escape this, it would execute this JavaScript code. But then, when Pagedown goes to convert this into a code tag, it adds `<pre>` tags around this section, so that the code displays as

```
    for(var i = 0; i &lt; 10; i++)
```

How can I get the code sections to display the proper unescaped characters, but also write this safely so it does not execute arbitrary JavaScript code? It seems like maybe I could have Django output the saved comment (escaped), and then go and unescape everything, and then re-escape all non code sections.

Are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The fix seems to be turning all `&amp;` into simply `&`, and therefore the HTML entities do render properly in the code sections. However before it would look something like `&amp;lt;` which would render as `&lt` instead of `&lt;` turning into `<`.

Used this method:

```
unhtmlEntityCode: function(code){
    code = code.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
    return code;
},
```